# ¿Existe algún plugin Oficial para Magento 2 de MercadoPago?

Tags: php, magento2, mercadopago

Tengo un eCommerce montado con Magento2 y necesito recibir pagos con MercadoPago.

¿Existe algún plugin oficial que esté actualizado?

Gracias!

Comment: https://github.com/mercadopago/cart-magento

Comment: Creo que esa es la versión para magento 1

Comment: Tenes info en el repositorio de [Github de Magento 2](https://github.com/mercadopago/cart-magento2), y también en el [sitio de desarrolladores](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/tools/modules/magento/magento2/) de Mercado Pago. Saludos!

Comment: facundofarias: esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Date por favor una vuelta por [tour] y [ask] para entender cómo formular preguntas respondibles. Después, dale a [edit] y actualiza tu pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Existe algún plugin oficial que esté actualizado?

`MercadoPago` en la web para desarrolladores ofrece un [módulo para Magento 2](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/tools/modules/magento/magento2/)

La [versión 1.0.1](https://github.com/mercadopago/cart-magento2/releases) fue liberada el *26/08/2016*.